Jest tests failing when using reactotron and __DEV__
I get the error:

Invariant Violation: TurboModuleRegistry.getEnforcing(...): 'DevMenu' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary. Bridgeless mode: false. TurboModule interop: false. Modules loaded: {"NativeModules":["SourceCode","PlatformConstants","DevSettings","BlobModule","Networking"],"TurboModules":[],"NotFound":["LogBox","DevMenu"]}


1 | import Reactotron from 'reactotron-react-native';
| ^
2 | import { reactotronRedux } from 'reactotron-redux';

I am using reactotron in my redux store:
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  enhancers: __DEV__ ? [Reactotron?.createEnhancer()] : [],

  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        /* ignore persistance actions */
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }).concat(sagaMiddleware),
});

Reactotron config:
import Reactotron from 'reactotron-react-native';
import { reactotronRedux } from 'reactotron-redux';

const reactotron = Reactotron.configure({
  name: 'myRAC',
})
  .useReactNative({
    networking: {
      ignoreUrls:
        /symbolicate|https:\/\/images\.contentstack\.io\/v3\/a|https:\/\/www\.google\.com\//,
    },
  })
  .use(reactotronRedux())
  .connect();
export default reactotron;

In my jest config:
  globals: {
    __DEV__: true,
  },

